# Multiple COUNT on Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables, one contains payment info, other one certificates received and the last one the person details like name, surname etc.

I'm trying to select entries from payment table where there is 4 or more entries and from certificate table where there is 1 or more entries.

My query looks like this but not getting the correct output.

```
SELECT count(a.`id`) AS count1, count(b.`id`) AS count2, c.`id`, c.`district`, c.`emp_code`, c.`last_name`, c.`first_name`, c.`title`, c.`gender`, c.`ethnic`, c.`eng_date`, c.`term_date`, c.`statn`, c.`statp`, c.`job`, c.`dept`, c.`ppoint`, c.`id_number`, c.`sira_number`, c.`sira_grade`, c.`sira_valid_date`, c.`imp_time`, c.`uid` 
FROM `z_training_payments` AS a  
LEFT JOIN `z_training_cert` AS b ON (a.`id_number`=b.`id_number` AND a.`uid`=b.`uid`) 
INNER JOIN `z_training_hr` AS c ON (a.`id_number`=c.`id_number` AND a.`uid`=c.`uid`) 
GROUP BY (a.`uid` AND b.`uid`) HAVING (count1 >= 4 AND count2 >= 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following:

```
SELECT a.`id`, a.`district`, a.`emp_code`, a.`last_name`, a.`first_name`, a.`title`, a.`gender`, a.`ethnic`, a.`eng_date`, a.`term_date`, a.`statn`, a.`statp`, a.`job`, a.`dept`, a.`ppoint`, a.`id_number`, a.`sira_number`, a.`sira_grade`, a.`sira_valid_date`, a.`imp_time`, a.`uid`, 
    COALESCE(b.count1,0) AS count1,
    COALESCE(c.count2,0) AS count2 
FROM `z_training_hr` AS a 
    INNER JOIN (
            SELECT COUNT(*) AS count1, uid 
            FROM `z_training_payments` 
            GROUP BY `uid` HAVING count1 >= 4 
        ) AS b 
        ON a.`uid` = b.`uid` 
    INNER JOIN (
            SELECT COUNT(*) AS count2, uid 
            FROM `z_training_cert` 
            GROUP BY `uid` HAVING count2 >= 1 
        ) AS c 
        ON a.`uid` = c.`uid`
```